# Use variables with --eval in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am trying to use the dynamic database name in the below bash script, but it fails with an error saying `invalid escape sequence`.

```
#!/bin/bash

...
...

db_name=test
db_existence=$(mongo mongodb+srv://$db_credentials$mongoatlas_host --eval 'db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf(\"$db_name\")' --quiet)
```

I also tried using double quotes with `--eval` and single quotes for DB name as in the below script, but still, it gives the same `invalid escape sequence` error.

```
db_existence=$(mongo mongodb+srv://$db_credentials$mongoatlas_host --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf(\'$db_name\')" --quiet)
```

It uses the variable name as it is if I don't use `\` escape character with `db_name`.

I can't hardcode the DB name as my database name is coming from another command.

I think that I might be missing something very fundamental in terms of bash scripting.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of those:

```
--eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf('$db_name')"

--eval 'db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf("'$db_name'")'

--eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf(\"$db_name\")"
```